# Why is my media query not working with Flexbox?

Tags: css, media-queries, flexbox

I'm building mobile first and using flexbox. I have three columns..

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="one"></div>
   <div id="two" class="hidden"></div>
   <div id="three" class="hidden"></div>
</div>
```

On mobile I want the hidden class hidden.

Although I'm designing mobile first the first CSS read is:

```
   #container {
            width: 87%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
```

Then I use a media query to hide the `.hidden`.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
            .hidden {
                display: none;
            }
        }
```

Then I go into Desktop styles and style the three divs like so

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
 #container {
                width: 93%;
                margin: 0 auto;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
            }

}
```

Why is it that the last two divs with the class of `hidden` are not hiding on mobile?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ek0q20m1/1/)

Comment: Any chance your mobile device is wider than 360px?

Comment: You're right. Wan't to add that as an answer?

Comment: Just FYI, if you want to test responsive design for different widths, you can always resize the browser window on your computer.

Comment: I would also add make sure you added a meta tag like: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"> Many mobile devices will use a much greater width unless they see that tag. The @meda width is not actually pixel for pixel on most mobile devices.

Comment: I tested it by adjusting the browser width. That's what through me as it wasn't chainging. Turns out 6S Plus is bigger than safari taken to the smallest size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mobile device is probably wider than 360px. Figure out what the correct width is and adjust your stylesheet accordingly.

Also, when possible, you should consider using a more generic media query (e.g. `(orientation: portrait)`) in order to avoid having to hard-code widths in your stylesheets.